# What is the best way to keep track of how many derived classes does a superclass have in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a project where a superclass has plenty of subclasses. I use methods that create randomly generated objects of subclasses and to estimate how many of subclasses exist I use a static variable. I try to remember always to increment it. But what if somebody else started working with this code? He might miss this step and as a result my random tests would pass no matter if his code worked properly. Is there any mechanism to avoid such scenario? Or maybe my design is completly wrong and I should change it somehow?

Edit:
I know how to count how many objects was created. I am looking for a mechanism to find out how many subclasses exist.

Comment: "My random generating methods base on a static field called counter"  what does this mean ? also what do you mean by "Remember" in the next sentence ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Basically, I have a set of derived classes and I randomly generate objects. To estimate how many subclasses I have I use a static variable in the base class. And I am asking whether there is a better way to indicate this number

Comment: You seem to be confusing classes with objects. Time to revise the basics!

Comment: Still not clear. Are you trying to count the objects or the subclasses? The objects can only be counted at runtime, and a static member variable that is automatically updated in the constructor/destructor of the base class is a good way. If, on the other hand, you want to know how many subclasses you have, that is, how many times you wrote `class Subclass12 : public Base {...};` then I think there's no way to do it at runtime. It's basically static code analysis.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/ ?

Comment: Sorry that you find it unclear. I know how to count created object and I don't know how to count amount of subclasses. And what I did was a static code analysis. I just wasn't sure if there are some mechanisms to do it in other way.

Comment: *I know how to count how many objects was created. I am looking for a mechanism to find out how many subclasses were created.*. subclasses are not created at run time but at compile time. So counting them should be done at compile time too. Or did you mean *of how many different subclasses objects were created at run time*? Then say so.

Comment: Yes, I want to know how many subclasses exist at compile time.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Why do you need to know how many subclasses exist ?

Comment: Maybe I've got it: is it a sort of code-coverage problem? You have written some code that tries to generate some objects for each subclass, to make sure everything is working (or, at least, constructor and destructor), and you would like to make sure that your tests cover all the possible cases, that is, all the possible subclasses? And you have manually counted how many you have, and let's say they are 30, then you have defined `static int subclassesCount = 30;` and when your tests create objects of 30 subclasses you are done, but if another developers adds subclasses and doesn't update

Comment: (continue) the variable your tests would give 100% coverage when they reach 30, that is, even though you have not tested the creation of objects of these new subclasses? Is that the problem? If that is the case, I think you should edit your question to better explain it, and then show the code you are using to make these tests (or at least the general structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or maybe my design is completly wrong and I should change it somehow?

I think it is. You could keep the instance counting outside the class hierarchy and control it through a set of (templated) factory functions. This would allow you to use this counting system (or not) and it would allow you to extend/customize it as you need.

**Edit**: Intrusive solution for counting specializations:

```
class Base // root of your hierarchy
{
protected:
    Base(char const * const type)
    {
        instances_.insert(type);
    }

    virtual ~Base() = 0;

public:
    static decltype(instances_.size()) CountSpecializations() const
    {
        return instances_.size();
    }

private:
    static std::set<std::string> instances_;
};

/// This is convenience code: clients could simply call 
/// Base(typeid(typename T).name()) on construction, witout it
template<typename T>
class TypedSpecialization: public Base
{
protected:
    TypedSpecialization() : Base(typeid(typename T).name()) {}
};
```

Client code:

```
// actual specialization (w/o TypedSpecialization it would inherit from Base)
class Specialization1: public TypedSpecialization<Specialization1>
{
public:
    Specialization1(): TypedSpecialization<Specialization1>() {}
};

int f()
{
    assert(0 == Base.CountSpecializations());

    Specialization1 s1, s2;
    assert(1 == Base.CountSpecializations());
}
```

The code doesn't actually count the number of existing specializations in the code base, but the number of distinct specializations that were instantiated since the application started.

Comment: Could you give me a simple example how might it look like?

Comment: I just saw that you are actually talking about different subclasses, not different instances. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, maybe that's not exactly what I was thinking of but I managed to figure it out after your guidelines.